# Populate shortcodes with table data and get next row

Tags: shortcode, wpdb

Let's say I have a database table `wp_myplugin_cars` that looks like this:

```
id   name    color   make
--   ----    -----   ----
1    Peter   Red     Ford
2    Jo      Blue    Nissan
3    Brian   Silver  Toyota
... plus n more rows
```

Let's say I have a plugin setting field which is a `wp_editor` and inside that, the user can choose how to display their data using my plugin. They might save something like:

```
<h1>Cars and people list</h1>
[myplugin-name] drives a [myplugin-color] [myplugin-make]
```

My problem is that (with my current knowledge), I can only output:

> Cars and people list
>
> Peter drives a Red Ford

So my question is: when adding shortcodes, how can I "move to the next row" just like the `Next Record` field in Microsoft Word mail merge. I.e., is the following possible?

```
<h1>Cars and people list</h1>
[myplugin-name] drives a [myplugin-color] [myplugin-make] [myplugin-NEXTRECORD]
```

The desired result being:

> Cars and people list
>
> Peter drives a Red Ford
>
> Jo drives a Blue Nissan
>
> Brian drives a Silver Toyota
>
> ... and so on...